# How to get user's geolocation with ESRI API for JS 3.16?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to add some button to find user's current geolocation. Can I do it with Esri API for JavaScript 3.16? I want something like Search widget. 
Also I have seen Locate widget, but it is from 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the geolocation button in JSAPI 3.x

[Locate Button](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_locate.html)

Remember to host your code with HTTPS or geolocation won't work in current versions of chrome